# JetBrains | Git | How to pull data but so that they don't be merged right away and you could see changes first in the Local Changes tab?

Tags: git, github, jetbrains-ide

Using JetBrains how to pull data but so that they don't be merged right away and you could see changes first in the Local Changes tab?

P.S. every time there is someone who wants to put a minus. Someone has problems with nerves

Answer (score 0):

For now, I decided to do like this, pull a commit from a branch and then `git reset --soft HEAD^`. This way I can see the last changes in the local changes tab